# How write letters using the buttons in various textboxs?

Tags: c#, .net, button, textbox, keyboard

I have small app and I want write text in different textboxs using buttons.
This is my code , but click on button  do not write text to text .
Please advise me.

What should I change?. In notepad it all works , but not in Textboxs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSBMl.png)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams param = base.CreateParams;
            param.ExStyle |= 0x08000000;
            return param;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            SendKeys.Send("A");
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            SendKeys.Send("B");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            SendKeys.Send("C");
        }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            SendKeys.Send("D");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It works when writing to notepad because there's only one (big) TextBox to write to. You will need to tell which TextBox you intend to write to when targetting your form.

Comment: Can you give more detail about your project ? Is it WPF or APP for Windows or are you using Xamarin for cross paltform deelopment?

Comment: @Filburt i have more textboxs, and how to detect,?

Comment: @UtkarshBais it is simple app for windows (winform) .net.

Comment: You need to the define the logic to find the right TextBox and then just set the focus to it. The MVVM way of doing something like this would be sending a Message with the according letter and have a MessageHandler deal with it, i.e. decide on the right TextBox. But teaching you MVVM would be way to broad to be put in an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should do something like this

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SendKeys.Send("B");
    txtBox.Text += "B";
}
```

But because you don't know which text box to edit, you need to introduce variable

```
private TextBox _currTextBox;

// wire all text boxes to this "enter" event
private void txtBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _currTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
}
// and accordingly

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _currTextBox.Text += "B";
}
```

Comment: This is for only one textbox, I need it for all textboxs,  where is focus

Comment: @matus.kasper read carefullty - this is for ALL text boxes. When you enter one - you select that one as current